# Provider trying to update my count when ever will I receive Notification?

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I am unable to update my Ui

//// HERE I AM GETTING THE UPDATE DATA IN CONSOLE BUT UNABLT TO UPDATE INSIDE MY UI

My NotificationCountClass

```
class NotificationCount extends ChangeNotifier{
   var count;

   NotificationCount({
     this.count =0,
   });

   addNotificationCount(){
    count++;
    notifyListeners();
    print("Notification Count $count"); 
  }

}
```

main : here i wrap the widget inside multiprovider so that i can use it any-where in my app

```
return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppService()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NotificationCount()),
          ],
          child: Consumer<AppService>(
            builder: (context, appService, child) {
              return GetMaterialApp(
                title: AppStrings.APP_TITLE,
                theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
                darkTheme: AppTheme.dartTheme,
                navigatorKey: GlobalVariable.navigatorKey,
                supportedLocales: [
                  Locale('en'),
                ],
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  CountryLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
                themeMode: appService.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                initialRoute: AppRouter.SPLASH_SCREEN,
                onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.router.generator,
                // routes: {
                //   "/":(context) =>Home(),
                //   "/AppChat" : (context) => AppChat(),
                // },
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                // home: AppChat(),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
```

// Using State with Consumer widget so that only required wiget rebuild

```
Consumer<NotificationCount>(
                                              builder: (context, value, child) {
                                                var count = value.count;
                                                print("Count of Not : $count");
                                                return Text(
                                                  "$count",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
```

getting NotificationCount class with provider but still unable to update UI

```
 final notificationCount = Provider.of<NotificationCount>(context , listen: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue on my side, and could fix it just by using the builder of MultiProvider instead of child.

Instead of

```dart
return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppService()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NotificationCount()),
          ],
          child: Consumer<AppService>(
```

write somthing like:

```dart
return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppService()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NotificationCount()),
        ],
        builder: (context, _) => Consumer<AppService>(
...
```

Comment: @fakhar-ilyas, did this answer solve your problem?